# Movie with laser shooting into space and two white guys at a bar

Tags: story-identification, movie

While flying to a wedding last weekend I caught a few glimpses of a movie that a fellow passenger was watching that looked interesting. I could not hear any audio and I only caught a couple minutes of what I presume was the beginning of the movie.

The first scene had a group of **scientists discussing aspects of 3 planets**, which I believe were Venus, Earth, and Mars. A screen shows that Venus's temperature was +250 degrees (I didn't see what scale).

Later, the shot zooms above what kind of looks like a solar collection tower in a mountainous area. Energy gathers together at the center, sort of Death Star style, and then **shoots a yellowish beam into space**.

The next scene shows two white guys at a dimly lit bar with some neon lights. I did not recognize any of the actors in any of these scenes, but it seems like a fairly recent movie, **probably no more than 10 years old**.

Comment: Was this a movie in a seat-back infotainment system or was it on someone's personal device? If it was the former, it might be listed on the airline's website/app or someone else might be flying that could look it up during their flight.

Comment: @TylerH great question. It was on a personal device.

Comment: Battleship maybe?

Comment: @Sorcefyre I looked into Battleship and it looks like that is it. Why don't you go ahead and post an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my (very short) comment. Could this be [*Battleship*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battleship_(film)) (2012)?

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1440129/):

> An international fleet of naval warships encounters an alien armada while on a Naval war games exercise and faces the biggest threat mankind has ever faced. An intense battle is fought on sea, land and air. If they lose, the world could face a major extinction event and an alien invasion. Will humans win this alien war, what are the aliens doing here, and what do they want?

Comment: I will say this isn't a *great* answer because neither the text nor the video clip show anything I described above (except there is a yellow beam shot upwards very briefly at 1:18). But Sorcefyre's comment did lead me to discovering that this was, indeed, the correct movie.